# Prove : $\int_{{π}/{4}}^{{π}/{2}} e^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\mathrm dx>\sqrt2$

Tags: calculus, inequality, definite-integrals

Exactly as the title says , we need to prove :

$$\int_\frac{π}{4} ^ \frac{π}{2} e^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\mathrm dx>\sqrt2$$

**My unsuccessful approach:**

I tried by searching for a function $f$ such that :

$$e^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}>f$$ and

$$\int_\frac{π}{4} ^ \frac{π}{2}f\mathrm dx = \sqrt2$$

Since the limits are in terms of $π$ while the integral should be equal to $\sqrt 2$ , the indefinite integral should be of the form having denominator equal to $π$. Unfortunately, I have never encountered such type of functions or integrals.

For the same reasons above, I also cannot think of functions to apply sandwich theorem.

I am looking for some elementary methods but all level of answers are welcome. Thanks !

Comment: Maybe $e^{\cos(x)+\cos^2(x)}\geq \cos(x)+\cos^2(x)\geq \cos(x)$ ? (I didn't check if the could work... it's just an idea...)

Comment: Where does that problem come from?

Comment: @Surb  Thanks, but $\int_\frac{π}{4} ^ \frac{π}{2} \cos x = 1-\frac{1}{\sqrt {2}}$ and $\int_\frac{π}{4} ^ \frac{π}{2} \cos x + \cos^2x = 3/4 -\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} + \frac{π}{8}$ which doesn't seem to help :(

Comment: @MartinR It was given in my coaching week test.

Comment: [NOT AN ANSWER, JUST FOR GRAPHICAL UNDERSTANDNING] https://www.desmos.com/calculator/cwlbnucpp2, your integral covers the region above x-axis, between the red strip and below the curve, and using the concept that this area is lesser than the area of the rectangular strip of blue region (basically the blue strip between $\frac{\pi}{4}$ and $\frac{\pi}{2}$ which is 2.618, implies 0.785<$\sqrt 2$<$\int_{{π}/{4}}^{{π}/{2}} e^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\mathrm dx$ < 2.618

Comment: @User0 Thanks.  I see that $0.785<\int_\frac{π}{4} ^ \frac{π}{2} e^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\mathrm dx<2.61$ but not sure how to introduce $\sqrt{2}$ here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $\,g(x)=\cos x+\cos^2x\,.$

It results that$$e^{g(x)}>1+g(x)+\frac12g^2(x)+\frac16g^3(x)\,.$$ Moreover, $$\int_{\frac{\pi}4}^{\frac{\pi}2}\left[1+g(x)+\frac12g^2(x)+\frac16g^3(x)\right]\!\mathrm dx=\\=\dfrac{7956+3135\pi-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\sqrt2\;.$$

Comment: How do we know that if I take one more term in the expansion of $e^{g(x)}$, the sum will not go lower? Do we need to prove that?

Comment: @sku, we know it because $g(x)\geqslant0$ on the interval $\left[\frac{\pi}4,\frac{\pi}2\right]$.

Comment: The last integral is tedious to evaluate. The last inequality is to be observed by doing numerical calculations by hand ? Anyway, thanks for the answer.

Comment: @An_Elephant, Since $$1+g(x)+\frac12g^2(x)+\frac16g^3(x)=1+\cos x+\frac32\cos^2x+\frac76\cos^3x+\cos^4x+\frac12\cos^5x+\frac16\cos^6x\;\;,$$ in order to evaluate the integral, it is sufficient to calculate $\int\cos^nx\,\mathrm dx\,$ for $\,n=1,2,3,4,5,6\,$ and it is not so difficult. For example,$$\int\cos^4\!x\,\mathrm dx=\frac38x+\frac14\sin(2x)+\frac1{32}\sin(4x)+c\;,$$$$\int\cos^6\!x\,\mathrm dx=\frac5{16}x\!+\!\frac14\sin(2x)\!-\!\frac1{48}\sin^3(2x)\!+\!\frac3{64}\sin(4x)\!+\!c\;.$$

Comment: Yes , it's elementary and not difficult. But What I said is that it's too lengthy.

Comment: @An_Elephant, in my opinion it is not so lengthy, you just need to calculate 6 integrals.

Comment: @An_Elephant, you can get the last inequality by hand in the following way:
$$\dfrac{7956+3135\pi-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\dfrac{7956+3135\cdot3.14-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\dfrac{7950+9800-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\dfrac{17750-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\dfrac{2\cdot5^3\cdot71-6712\sqrt2}{5760}=\dfrac{2\cdot5^3\cdot50\cdot\frac{71}{50}-6712\sqrt2}{5760}=\dfrac{12500\cdot1.42-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\dfrac{12500\sqrt2-6712\sqrt2}{5760}>\dfrac{5788\sqrt2}{5760}>\sqrt2$$

Comment: **(1)**-But how can we say that $π>3.14$ ? I know that $π>\frac{22}{7}$ but we also know that $\frac{22}{7}> 3.14$. **(2)**- When I said lengthy, I didn't meant that it's lengthy in absolute sense. I said it in relative sense to my exam time. ( Which on average is equal to 2 minutes per question). Thanks !

Comment: actually $\frac{22}{7}$ > $\pi$ and not $\frac{22}{7}$ < $\pi$, also $\pi$ >3.14 is self - explanatory. refer this for proof https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80 (also dont worry much such questions will never appear in contest math)

Comment: @An_Elephant, you are absolutely right when you say that calculating that integral requires more time than $2$ or $3$ minutes.  Regarding $\pi$, we know that $\pi=3.14159…$, so it is obvious that $\pi>3.14$, moreover, as User0 pointed out, actually $\frac{22}7>\pi\,.$

Comment: @User0 Oops sorry I mis-remembered that integral inequality. Also, it wasn't related to contest math practice.

Comment: @Angelo Yes I get it. Thanks.

Comment: @An_Elephant, wish you all the best for jee advanced!!

Comment: @User0 Thanks very much. (albeit I have no hope left)

Answer (score 3):

*Remarks*: The trick is to use $\mathrm{e}^{u} = \mathrm{e}^a\mathrm{e}^{u - a}
\ge \mathrm{e}^a (1 + u - a)$ by choosing appropriate constant $a$.
More details are given at the end.

We have
\begin{align*}
 I &= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \mathrm{e}\cdot \mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x} - 1}\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^{1/2}\mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x} - 1/2}\,\mathrm{d} x\\[6pt]
 &\ge \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \mathrm{e}\cdot (1 + \cos x + \cos^2{x} - 1)\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^{1/2}(1 + \cos x + \cos^2{x} - 1/2)\,\mathrm{d} x \tag{1}\\[6pt]
 &= \mathrm{e}\left(- \frac14 + \frac{1}{24}\pi - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} + \frac58 \sqrt 3\right)
 + \mathrm{e}^{1/2}\left(-\frac58\sqrt 3 + \frac16\pi + 1\right)\\[6pt]
 &> 2.7\left(- \frac14 + \frac{1}{24}\cdot 3.14 - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} + \frac58 \sqrt 3\right)
 + 1.64\left(-\frac58\sqrt 3 + \frac16\cdot 3.14 + 1\right)\\[6pt]
 &> \sqrt 2
\end{align*}
where we use $\mathrm{e}^u \ge 1 + u$ for all $u\in \mathbb{R}$ in (1),
and $\mathrm{e} > 2.7$, and $\mathrm{e}^{1/2} > 1.64$, and $\pi > 3.14$.

**More details for the trick**:

First, we try
\begin{align*}
 I &= \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^a\cdot\mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x} - a}\,\mathrm{d} x\\
  &\ge \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^a\cdot (1 + \cos x + \cos^2{x} - a)\,\mathrm{d} x\\
  &= \mathrm{e}^a \left(\frac34 + \frac38\pi - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} a\right).
\end{align*}
Let
$$f(a) := \mathrm{e}^a \left(\frac34 + \frac38\pi - \frac{\sqrt 2}{2} - \frac{\pi}{4} a\right).$$
We have
$$f'(a) = \frac{\pi}{4}\mathrm{e}^a
\left(\frac12 + \frac{3-2\sqrt 2}{\pi} -a \right).$$
Thus, $f(a)$ achieves its global maximum at $a_0 = \frac12 + \frac{3-2\sqrt 2}{\pi}$.

However $f(a_0) < \sqrt 2$. Thus, we split the integral into two parts i.e.
$$I = \int_{\pi/4}^{\pi/3} \mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d} x + \int_{\pi/3}^{\pi/2} \mathrm{e}^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\,\mathrm{d} x$$
and do something similar for each part.

Comment: Thanks ! But I've expected for something more elementary (because our test was basic). Like some nice "$f$" such that $\int f = \sqrt{2}$ directly instead of hard calculations. But thanks for another approach.

Comment: @An_Elephant OK. I will try if there is better solution.

Comment: This is a smart and simple (after reading it) solution

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thanks.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Yes. The solution is smart but the final numericals in last are not trivial. ( Atleast for students like us )

Comment: @An_Elephant. I am preparing an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Since, for the consiered range, the cosine is not negative, using
$$e^{\cos(t)+\cos^2(t)}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n\cos^n(t)$$ we shall just add a succession of $\color{red}{\text{positive}}$ terms

The $a_n$ are given by
$$a_n=\frac{2 a_{n-2}+a_{n-1}}{n} \qquad \text{with} \qquad a_0=a_1=1$$

On the other side, we know the reduction formula for $$I_n=\int \cos^n(x)\,dx$$ and that
$$J_n=\int_{\frac \pi 4}^{\frac \pi 2} \cos^n(x)\,dx ~~> ~0$$

We just need to look at the partial sum
$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^p a_n\, J_n$$

We do not need many terms since
$$S_4=\frac{2632-2272 \sqrt{2}+1233 \pi }{2304}=1.42903 ~~>~\sqrt 2$$

Comment: Thanks. But how $S_4$ is equal to the given integral ? Or is it that $S_4<\int_\frac{π}{4} ^ \frac{π}{2} e^{\cos x + \cos^2{x}}\mathrm dx$ ?

Comment: @An_Elephant. SInce we only add positive terms, just find $p$ such that $S_p \sqrt 2$. That all. If If I continue the process, we shall be very close to the "exact" value of the integral.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici The recurrence relation is nice.